# Not able to change header footer border and background colors in datatables in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, datatable, datatables

I am trying to customize my datatable but not getting much stuff regarding this. Tried changing css but that too doesn't work.

**datatable.component.html:**

```
    <style>
    .table1.dataTable  {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 11px;
        border-bottom-color: #dddddd;
        border-top-color: #dddddd;
    }
    /* .table1.dataTable thead th,
    .table1.dataTable thead td {
      padding: 10px 18px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid #f5f0f0;
    }
    .table1.dataTable thead tr th {
      background-color: green;
    } */
    .table1.dataTable.compact thead th, .table1.dataTable.compact thead td {
      background-color: black;
      color: white;
    }
    </style>
<div class="animated fadeIn">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" class="table1 row-border hover cell-border compact stripe" style="width:100%"  id="tableSwiftMessage">
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**datatable.component.ts:**

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.defaultTradeRefNo = null;
        this.dateApplySelect = "Actual Settlement Date";
        this.defaultNominal = 0;
        this.defaultIsin = "";
        this.defaultMessageType = "MT-544";
        this.defaultNetSetlAmt = 0;

        this.dtOptions = {
            responsive : true,
            dom : 'Rlfrtip',
            data : [],
            scrollX : true,
            lengthMenu: [10, 15, 20, 30, 50],
            pageLength: 10,
            searching: true,
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: -1,
                    className: 'dt-body-right'
                }
              ],
            columns: [
                {
                    title: 'Message Type',
                    data: 'MESSAGETYPE'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Short Name',
                    data: 'SHORTNAME'
                }
            ],
            rowCallback: (row: Node, data: any, index: number) => {
              $(row).on('click', () => {
                $("#tableMessage tr").removeClass('active');
                this.selectedtMessageList = [];
                this.addThisMessageToArray(data);
                if (this.isMessageSelected(data) == true) {
                  $(row).addClass('active');
                }
              });
              // $(row).find('td').attr('title', data);
              $(row).find('td').css('text-overflow', 'ellipsis').css('white-space', 'nowrap').css('overflow', 'hidden').css('max-width', '25px');
              return row;
            }
        };
    }
```

I want to change the color of table section border that is between the table header and the table body and between the table body and the table footer. By default it's black in color. Also, i want to change table header background and text colors.

Comment: Are you using a css library?

Comment: @Jeremy : I am using visual studio code where there are 2 files - 1 is .html file containing css and html and other containing typescript code.

Comment: Okay, I ask because you have some classes on your HTML that are not inside your CSS. For example, `col-sm-12` is a bootstrap class. And `card`, `card-body`. Classes that you are not using.

Comment: @Gunnet, you sould use style in your component:https://angular.io/guide/component-styles, **not** a tag with `<style>`. In Angular is prefered use `[ngClass]` or `[ngStyle]` instead of addClass at JavaScript's style. Really I suggest not use jQuery or librarys based in jQuery when you work with Angular or at least not use jQuery to change class of elements, see https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives. Angular are variables (in .ts) that you use in your .html. When change a variable in .ts, this makes that the .html change its apparence